# ¿Como conectarme a un webservices PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Necesito conectarme a un Web services estoy utilizando PHP para hacer la conexión. Los dejo los detalles del xml tanto del request como la respuesta

Este es el request

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:head="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/HeaderRequest" xmlns:con="http://prueba.com/ARQ/EMP/ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuario">
   <soap:Header>
      <head:HeaderRequest>
         <head:Username></head:Username>
         <head:Company></head:Company>
         <head:AppName></head:AppName>
         <head:IdClient></head:IdClient>
         <head:ReqDate>2018-08-21T17:59:19.998-03:00</head:ReqDate>
      </head:HeaderRequest>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <con:ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuarioRequest>
         <con:rutCliente>123456789-K</con:rutCliente>
      </con:ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuarioRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Este es el la respuesta del xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header xmlns:con="http://prueba.com/ARQ/EMP/ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuario" xmlns:head="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/HeaderRequest">
      <ns1:HeaderResponse xmlns:ns1="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/HeaderResponse">
         <ns1:IdServer>prueba.com:8000</ns1:IdServer>
         <ns1:ReqSrvDate>2018-08-21T17:59:19.998-03:00</ns1:ReqSrvDate>
         <ns1:RespSrvDate>2019-05-02T11:05:24.635-04:00</ns1:RespSrvDate>
      </ns1:HeaderResponse>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body xmlns:con="http://prueba.com/ARQ/EMP/ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuario" xmlns:head="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/HeaderRequest">
      <con:ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuarioResponse>
         <con:ResultadoServicio>
            <con:esClienteServicioMigrado>false</con:esClienteServicioMigrado>
            <con:sistemaOrigen>A</con:sistemaOrigen>
         </con:ResultadoServicio>
         <con:ResultadoEjecucion>
            <res:ejecucionExitosa xmlns:res="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/ResultadoEjecucion">true</res:ejecucionExitosa>
            <res:codigoError xmlns:res="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/ResultadoEjecucion">0</res:codigoError>
            <res:mensaje xmlns:res="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/ResultadoEjecucion">Ejecución Exitosa</res:mensaje>
         </con:ResultadoEjecucion>
      </con:ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuarioResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Lo que hace este xml es mostrar si un cliente esta migrado o no por cual se le envía el RUT a consultar.

Lo que he intentado hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", -1);  
    error_reporting('E_ALL');



    $fields="";
    $fields .= '<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:head="http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/HeaderRequest" 
    xmlns:con="http://prueba.com/ARQ/EMP/ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuario">';
    $fields .= '<soap:Header>';
    $fields .= '    <head:HeaderRequest>';
    $fields .= '        <head:Username></head:Username>';
    $fields .= '        <head:Company></head:Company>';
    $fields .= '        <head:AppName></head:AppName>';
    $fields .= '        <head:IdClient></head:IdClient>';
    $fields .= '        <head:ReqDate>'.date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z').'</head:ReqDate>';
    $fields .= '    </head:HeaderRequest>';
    $fields .= '</soap:Header>';
    $fields .= '<soap:Body>';
    $fields .= '    <con:ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuarioRequest>';
    $fields .= '        <con:rutCliente>123456789-K</con:rutCliente>';
    $fields .= '    </con:ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuarioRequest>';
    $fields .= '</soap:Body>';
    $fields .= '</soap:Envelope>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'prueba.com:8000/consultarEstadoMigracionUsuario?wsdl'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$fields");
    $r = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($r,null, 0, 'soap', true);
    $xml->registerXPATHNamespace('head', 'http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/HeaderResponse');
    $xml->registerXPATHNamespace('con', 'http://prueba.com/GLOBAL/EMP/ConsultarEstadoMigracionUsuarioResponse');
    $certificado=json_encode($xml->children('soap',true)->ResultadoEjecucion->children('con',true));

    //return $fields;
    $respuesta['request'] = $fields;
    $respuesta['response'] = json_decode($certificado,TRUE);

?>
```

Al ejecutar en el navegador no me muestra ni me da error no se porque no me esta generando ninguna respuesta

Por favor si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal me ayude

Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar la clase ya construida de PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php

Eso te ayudará  a no tener que lidiar con temas de curl, etc.

Ejemplo:

```
// Inicializa el WS con el WSDL $client = new
SoapClient("http://localhost:10139/Service1.asmx?wsdl"); 
// Haz la llamada a la función: 
$response = $client->__soapCall("Function1", array($params));
```

Saludos